# Error while building migrated project in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I am developing an hybrid application for Android and iOS using IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation Studio.

I am facing an issue when migrating the project from  MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 to  MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 (7.1.0.00.20151005-1721).

It seems the `WorklightSDK` folder is missing when the native folder gets created.
It works fine if I manually add the missing folder.

It also works fine when the project is auto migrated in Eclipse. However, when I try to import and use the migrated project again, I am facing the mentioned issue.
Not able to find any issue logged for the same.

Comment: Can you provide your MobileFirst (Studio) project Before it was migrated so the error could be experienced and debugged? Or any other project...

Answer (score 0):

There are some inconsistencies in the question...

> It seems the WorklightSDK folder is missing when the native folder gets created. It works fine if I manually add the missing folder.

If it is missing, then where are you adding it from? the old worklightSDK folder from 7.0? that's obviously not a solution

> It also works fine when the project is auto migrated in Eclipse. However, when I try to import and use the migrated project again, I am facing the mentioned issue.

If the project "auto migrates", it means that on import it did get upgraded (successfully). But then you say that on a second import - of the already migrated project - it fails. what fails?

*What is the error you see in the Eclipse console when you build the project?*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
I don't get any error while building the project but I am getting an error while running it using xcode 6.2
The error I get is :

Missing file WLAppDelegate.h